# Transpose visible cells till last column

Tags: vba, excel

I've an excel sheet which basically will have a variable numbers in Columns A till C, it gets filtered to unique values based on `for next` loop I've achieved this and next  I'm trying to copy the visible range starting from column F till `last column`(since variable columns each time when filters)  and transpose it vertically in new sheet.The approach that I've used is counting each visible row and copy till end. Here's the code.

```
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set WS2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("3")
L2 = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For Each CELL In ws.Range("F2:F" & L2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    i = CELL.Row
    L3 = ws.Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    ws.Range(Cells(i, 6), Cells(i, L3)).Copy
    L4 = WS2.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
    WS2.Cells(L4 + 1, 4).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
Next CELL
```

[image: Filtered range]

But is there any alternate way to copy and transpose cells that have values from Column F till last column?In the above example starting from `F108:H110` select and copy only cells that have values in it.

Answer (score 1):

SpecialCells is a member of `Range` returns a range Object.  Knowing that we can chain them together `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)` to narrow our range.  This will give you a non-continuous range.  You cannot use the copy command with a Non-continuous.  If you assign it to an array, the array will only be partially populated.  You must iterate over it with a `For Each` loop.

```
Sub SelectVisibleNonBlankCells()
    Dim c As Range, r As Range
    Dim L2 As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("3")

       L2 = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
       Set r = .Range("F2:F" & L2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

    End With

    For Each c In r

    Next

End Sub
```

I would just iterate over the all the rows checking for visibility.  Next just add the data to an an array and use range resize to fill the destination range.

`Sub TransposeVisibleCells()

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("3")
        Dim ColumnCount As Integer, lastRow As Long, RowCount As Long, x As Long, y As Long
        Dim arData

        lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        ColumnCount = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        ReDim arData(ColumnCount, RowCount)
        For x = 2 To lastRow

            If Not .Rows(x).Hidden Then
                ReDim Preserve arData(ColumnCount, RowCount)

                For y = 1 To ColumnCount
                    arData(y -1, RowCount) = .Cells(x, y).Value
                Next

                RowCount = RowCount + 1
            End If
        Next

    End With

    Worksheets("Transposed Data").Range("A1").Resize(ColumnCount, RowCount) = arData
End Sub`

Comment: ,My problem is not selecting all the visible cells but only to select the visible cells which contains data.Just for an instance in the above example in the range of `F108:H110`select only `F108:H108 & :F109 & :F110:H110`

Comment: So you don't want columns without data?

Comment: Thanks @Thomas,just curious to know why excel don't copy if I use `.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).copy` .if I use `select` it would select but it doesn't copy.What is the reason?

Comment: Excel cannot copy non-continuous ranges. They probably prevent this so that they can insure consistent results.